# ContextMenu OnClose handler

Tags: c#, winforms

For some reason I am unable to find the OnClose handler on a System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu, I need the OnClose event to check when the ContextMenu is closed if a menu option was selected, if not to reset a value to new Point(0, 0).

I've been searching the web for a few hours but the only thing I seem to find on ContextMenu is System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu, what is the difference between the two.

Comment: This is not how you handle contextmenus, you should be adding event handlers to respond to a user action on a contextmenu instead of checking after the menu is closed.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984319(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Then how would I detect if the user has exited the ContextMenu without selecting an item? That is what I am attempting to do with this.

Comment: It is a .NET 1.x control, replaced by ContextMenuStrip.  Pretty unclear what problem you are trying to solve, a context menu always closes when you click a menu item.

Comment: I am drawing a square on screen when the context menu is opened, if the user presses to open the form the square should stay until the form is closed, if the user picks the option to do nothing (Click outside of the ContextMenu) the square should dissapear.

That is why I need to have the "OnClose" event, to check inside of that event if the form is open, if its not remove the square, otherwise let the OnClose event of the form remove it.

Comment: I've fixed my Issue, due to not having enough reputation I will have to wait a few hours before I can answer my own question, when this period has expired I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue, I've switched to ContextMenuStrip which is (Despite what I first though) basicly the same as the ContextMenu, I thought it could only dock to the top bar.

Because I am now using the ContextMenuStrip I could use the ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs from the Closed event to check if an item was selected or the focus was lost, which is exactly what I wanted.

Thanks for your help everyone.